# How do I move variables between Classes and functions without them changing?

Tags: python, function, class, pygame

I am fairly new to OOP and pygame, so these may be some stupid and basic questions - but I've been stuck on this for days so anything would help.

I am creating a variable called position3 within Gun.shoot(), I want this variable to move to Bullet.reposition() as Bullet.reposition is called upon. I then want the position3 variable to move to the Bullet.update() function, which gets called upon by a different process elsewhere in the code. During this whole process, the position3 variable should not change but should stay the same. I have managed to get the position3 variable to move to Bullet.reposition() from Gun.shoot(), however I can now not get it into Bullet.update(). Help!

```
class Bullet(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.Surface((5,5))
        self.image.fill(red)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        # self.rect.center = (200,200)
        self.positionofm = (23,0)
        self.pos = vec(300,300)
        self.centerlocation = vec(0,0)
        self.position3 = vec(0,0)

    def update(self):
        self.position3 = reposition.position3
        print("update",self.position3)
        # self.rect.center = self.position3
        self.centerlocation = random.randint(200,400),random.randint(200,400)
        self.rect.center =(self.centerlocation)




    def reposition(self,position3):
        print("repositioning")
        self.centerlocation = random.randint(200,400),random.randint(200,400)
        self.rect.move(position3)
        print("regular",position3)
        self.position3 = position3
        print("First update",self.position3)




class Gun(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.Surface((30,5), pg.SRCALPHA)
        self.image.fill(black)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.original_image = self.image
        self.rect.center = (WIDTH/2 , HEIGHT/2)
        self.pos = vec(WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2)
        self.offset = vec(20, 0)
        self.angle=0
        self.position2=vec(0,0)
        # self.bullet = Bullet()

    def shoot(self):
        self.BulletEndPos=vec(0,0)
        self.BulletEndPos=vec(pg.mouse.get_pos())
        # print(self.BulletEndPos,"akshgdjasgdas")
        position2x=self.position2[0]
        position2y=self.position2[1]
        position3=vec(0,0)
        position3=(math.floor(position2x)),(math.floor(position2y))
        Bullet.reposition(self, position3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well your code snippet already has everything you need there you just need to remove the line

```
self.position3 = reposition.position3
```

Given that reposition is not an object and will not hold a attribute

The value for position3 is already updated for the object on the reposition method and written in the Bullet object attribute. Another way you could do it would be to rewrite update() somewhat like this:

```
def update(self, position3= None):
    position_3 = position3 if position3 is not None else self.position3
    print("update",position_3)
    # self.rect.center = position_3
    self.centerlocation = random.randint(200,400),random.randint(200,400)
    self.rect.center =(self.centerlocation)
```

This gives you more freedom to pass position3 somewhere else in the code if needed while retaining the logic.

Now just to clarify a few things:

1. When you write a class you are just declaring the overall structure of the class and not creating any instance of it.
2. The self keyword refers to the referred instance of the class object, so you need to create an instance of the object that can keep those variables.

Keeping that in mind on your last line of method shoot you are doing nothing, has there is no bullet created to be repositioned and updated. So you kinda need to change your Gun class to this:

```
class Gun(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.Surface((30,5), pg.SRCALPHA)
        self.image.fill(black)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.original_image = self.image
        self.rect.center = (WIDTH/2 , HEIGHT/2)
        self.pos = vec(WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2)
        self.offset = vec(20, 0)
        self.angle=0
        self.position2=vec(0,0)
        self.bullet = Bullet()

    def shoot(self):
        self.BulletEndPos=vec(0,0)
        self.BulletEndPos=vec(pg.mouse.get_pos())
        # print(self.BulletEndPos,"akshgdjasgdas")
        position2x=self.position2[0]
        position2y=self.position2[1]
        position3=vec(0,0)
        position3=(math.floor(position2x)),(math.floor(position2y))
        self.bullet.reposition(self, position3)
```

OOP might be confusing at times especially at the beginning so you can try some other resources online (e.g. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_classes_objects.htm)

Comment: You're an absolute legend. This has been very helpful, thank you so much!!!!